# Open a new window and submit a form with a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click on submit button then :

first : open a new window to display process (by ajax call)

second : submit current form (processing time consuming job)

on Click of submit following JQuery function is being called :

```
function submitForm(){
    window.open('displayGetStatus.action?id=' + p_id ); 
    $("#frmStartSomeTask").attr("action","executeDatabaseOperation.action").submit();
}
```

**Result** : second window is opened and waiting for process to start but form on first window is not submitted so process is not started.

Please help how can i get this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why set the attr `action` in function `submitForm`?

Comment: @RenePot, the code was better as it had put Anant

Comment: @andresdescalzo yes, my bad. Fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Add the `window.open` call to the `onsubmit` of the form. In pure JS...

```
document.getElementById(frmStartSomeTask).onsubmit = function () {
    window.open('displayGetStatus.action?id=' + p_id ); 
}
```

you can modify this for jQuery if you so desire:

```
$("#frmStartSomeTask").submit(function () {
    window.open('displayGetStatus.action?id=' + p_id ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to open a window and then submit a form?

If so, your submit functionality doesn't look right. It's actually very simple to submit a form using plain Javascript...

```
function submitForm() {
    window.open('displayGetStatus.action?id=' + p_id );  
    document.getElementById("frmStartSomeTask").submit();
}
```